# WireMock - Stub for Request Containing JSON Attribute

Tags: java, wiremock

I'm trying to mock for the same request URL (multiple times), with different responses according to the JSON Body content.

My Request JSON is build dynamically so I can't statically use the `equalToJson` function on the Mock.

I have the same JSON like this:

```
{
    // Changes according to the request
    "task": "TEXT_ENTITY_RECOGNITION",
    "category": "TEXT",
    "data": content
}
```

What's the best approach for the `wireMockServer` stubs?

I'm trying something like this

```
wireMockServer.stubFor(post(urlEqualTo("/request"))
                        .withRequestBody(containing("TEXT_ENTITY_RECOGNITION"))
                        .withHeader("Content-Type", equalTo("application/json"))
                        .willReturn(aResponse()
                                .withStatus(201)
                                .withHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
.withBody(mockedJson)));
```

I have not found any sample of anything like this on the documentation.
Thanks!

Comment: Is there anything [JSON Path](http://wiremock.org/docs/request-matching/#json-path) doesn't support for you in WireMock?

Answer (score 1):

WireMock provides Several Content Pattern EqualToPattern and ContainsPattern are few of them. Try Something like :

```
StringValuePattern urlPattern = new EqualToJsonPattern("/request", true, true);
        MappingBuilder mappingBuilder = WireMock.post(new UrlPattern(urlPattern, false));
        StringValuePattern requestBodyPattern = new ContainsPattern("TEXT_ENTITY_RECOGNITION");
        mappingBuilder.withRequestBody(requestBodyPattern).withHeader("Content-Type", new EqualToJsonPattern("application/json", true, true));
        ResponseDefinitionBuilder response = WireMock.aResponse().withBody("Successful Custom Body Response").withStatus(201).withHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        mappingBuilder.willReturn(response);
        wireMockServer.stubFor(mappingBuilder);
```

This works well for me.

Answer (score 0):

Wiremock has the containing function, the way for calling is WireMock.containing

```
wireMockServer.stubFor(post(urlEqualTo("/request"))
                    .withRequestBody(WireMock.containing("TEXT_ENTITY_RECOGNITION"))
                    .withHeader("Content-Type", equalTo("application/json"))
                    .willReturn(aResponse()
                            .withStatus(201)
                            .withHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                            .withBody(mockedJson)));
```